# error in javascript: ReferenceError: thisForm is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming, this is a school assignment, but I cannot figure out where I did something wrong in my code.
I know that is says that "thisForm is not defined", but I think I did define it, could you guys have a quick look at my code and tell me where I did something wrong?

**dom-events.js:**

```
// globale variabelen
var afbeeldingen = new Array (
    "galaxy-s4.png",
    "ipad.jpg",
    "laptop.jpg");
var max = afbeeldingen.length;
var randomIndex=0;
function showklok()
{
    randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * max));
    document.getElementById("media").src = afbeeldingen[randomIndex];
}

function formcheck(thisform)
{
    postcode = thisForm.postcode.value;
    for(var i=0; i < postcode.length; i++)
    {
        var c = postcode.charAt(i);
        if(c == " ")
        {
            alert("Postcode mag geen spaties hebben");
            thisForm.postcode.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**dom-events.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta   http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>DOM events</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dom-events.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(
            '<form name="klok"> ' + 
            '<input type="text" ' + 
            'name="display" ' + 
            'size="8" ' + 
            'style="background-color: #30CE28; font-size:44px" >' + 
            '</form>');

        var nu = new Date();
        var uur = nu.getHours();
        var min = nu.getMinutes();
        var sec = nu.getSeconds();
        var alterneren = 0;
        function showklok()
        {
            min=((min < 10) ? "0" : "") + min;
            if (alterneren)
            {
                document.klok.display.value=uur + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
                alterneren = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                document.klok.display.value=uur + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
                alterneren = 1;
            }

            nu = new Date();
            uur = nu.getHours();
            min = nu.getMinutes();
            sec = nu.getSeconds();
            setTimeout("showklok()",1000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="showklok();">
    <div 
    <a href="javascript:showklok(randomIndex);">
        <img src="../images/ipad.jpg" id="media" width="8%"  onmouseover="this.width=this.width*1.5" onmouseout=    "this.width=this.width/1.5">
    </a>
</div>
<div style="width: 200px">
    <form action="mailto:email@adres.nl"
    name="custform"
    method="post" 
    onsubmit="return(formcheck(this));"
    name="custform" method="post" >

    <fieldset style="padding-left: 25px">
        <legend>Besteldformulier</legend>
        <label for="man">Man: </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="geslacht" id="man" value="m"/>
        <label for="vrouw">Vrouw: </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="geslacht" id="vrouw" value="v"/>

        <input required type="text" id="voornaam" placeholder="vult uw voornaam in">
        <input required type="text" id="achternaam" placeholder="vult uw achternaam in">
        <input required type="text" id="leeftijd" placeholder="vult uw leeftijd in" onchange="if (document.custform.leeftijd.value <=17)
        {
            alert('Minderjarig');
        }"
        />

        <input required type="text" id="plaats" placeholder="vult uw woonplaats in">
        <input required type="text" id="postcode" placeholder="vult uw postcode in">
        <input required type="text" id="e-mail" placeholder="vult uw e-mail in">
        <input required type="text" id="06" placeholder="vult uw 06 in">
        <input required type="password" id="password" placeholder="vult uw wachtwoord in">
        <input required type="password" id="password" placeholder="wachtwoord nogmaals">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset style="padding-left: 25px">
        <legend>Bestelling</legend>
        <label for="smartphone"><br />Smartphone: </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gadget" id="smartphone" value="s" />
        <label for="laptop"><br />Laptop: </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gadget" id="laptop" value="l" />
        <label for="tablet"><br />Tablet: </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="gadget" id="tablet" />
        <br />
        <select name="bezorging">
            <option value="" default selected>Selecteer bezorging</option>
            <option value="express">Express</option>
            <option value="dag">Dag</option>
            <option value="week">Week</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <div id=express-info" style="display:none">Express bestelling</div>
        <div id=dag-info" style="display:none">Dag bestelling</div>
        <div id=week-info" style="display:none">Week bestelling</div>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Verzenden"
        onmouseover="style.color='green'" 
        onmouseout="style.color='black'"
        />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<label for="man">Man: </label>
<input type="radio" name="geslacht" id="man" value="m" onchange="if(document.custform.man.checked == true)
{
    alert('Welkom meneer!');
}"
/>
<label for="vrouw">Vrouw: </label>
<input type="radio" name="geslacht" id="vrouw" value="v" onchange="if(document.custform.vrouw.checked == true)
{
    alert('Welkom mevrouw!');
}"
/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see the difference between `thisform` and `thisForm`?

Comment: Dammit, how could I have missed that!
I've looked everywhere in the code, I think I need a brake.
Thank you very much.

Comment: There are IDEs that can highlight that error. Among them, WebStorm or IntelliJ IDEA. I think static analysis would also filter it, e.g: if you put your code within a js file and run jshint on it. Running in strict mode would help you as well.